# Pythagoreisch vs. pythagoräisch

Tags: adjective, spelling

Warum liest man fast überall *pythagoreisch* anstatt *pythagoräisch*? *Apfel* -> *Äpfel*, also auch *Pythagoras* -> *pythagoräisch*.

Update: Nachdem so ziemlich jeder hier mein Beispiel mit dem Apfel für abwegig hält, erfolgt eine Korrektur: *Maß* -> *mäßig*. Da hat man dann eine Ableitung vom Substantiv zum Adjektiv.

Answer (score 8):

Die Form "pythagoräisch" ist zumindest in der mathematischen Literatur die allgemein übliche, so dass ich "pythagoreisch" nach wie vor für einen Anglizismus halte. Warum sonst nicht auch "europeisch" anstatt "europäisch"?

Answer (score 5):

Die Ableitung eines Adjektivs von einem Substantiv (die in etwa so viel mit der Pluralbildung eines Substantivs zu tun hat wie Äpfel mit Philosophen) gehorcht je nach Art und Herkunft des Substantivs [unterschiedlichen Regeln](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules11110). Was die adjektivische Ableitung von antiken Namen wie Augustus, Sophokles oder Pythagoras betrifft, wird regelmäßig das Suffix -isch verwendet. Dafür fällt ebenso regelmäßig die letzte Silbe (-us, -es oder -as) weg (anders bei der Endsilbe -on: Apollon -> apoll**inisch**; jedoch Platon -> platonisch, ebenso Solon -> solon**isch**).

Vor dem Suffix wird regelmäßig entweder ein ä oder ein e eingefügt (Augustus -> august**eisch** [nicht augustüisch]; Sophokles -> sophokl**eisch**; Pythagoras -> pythagor**eisch**; anders z.B. Sokrates -> sokrat**isch**; Dionysos -> dionys**isch**; Chaos -> chao**tisch**; Eros -> ero**tisch**), und zwar **unabhängig von der Vokalisierung der weggefallenen letzten Silbe**. Zwar [findet man die Version mit "ä" auch in der Schriftsprache](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22august%C3%A4isch%22&tbm=bks), insgesamt scheint jedoch in allen Fällen das "e" gegenüber dem "ä" bevorzugt zu werden.

Über die Gründe kann man letztlich nur spekulieren. Ich vermute, dass das "ä" veraltet wirkt - ebenso, wie bis ins Jahr 1850 noch "echt" und "ächt" gleichauf lagen, seither jedoch die Variante "ächt" abfiel und schließlich ganz verschwand:

[image]

Ein "Fugenvokal" findet sich übrigens auch im Englischen, wenn aus dem Namen ein Adjektiv abgeleitet wird: Augustus -> augustean; Pythagoras -> pythagorean; aber (analog zum Suffix -isch): Platon -> platonic (nicht platoneic).

Comment: „Die Ableitung eines Adjektivs von einem Substantiv (die in etwa so viel mit der Pluralbildung eines Substantivs zu tun hat wie Äpfel mit Philosophen)“
*Maß* -> *mäßig*, neuerdings auch *Aufwand* -> *aufwändig*. Brauchst du noch ein paar Beispiele?

Comment: @Trash Dein Beispiel war "Apfel"->"Äpfel" ->(?)"äpflisch"(?)

Comment: Lieber @Thrash , die Anzahl ist nicht das Problem, sondern die Beliebigkeit des "Arguments".

Comment: Deswegen hab ich doch mein Beispiel korrigiert und jetzt *Maß* -> *mäßig* genommen.

Comment: Welche Beliebigkeit? Substantiv -> Adjektiv. Jetzt passt es doch.

Comment: @Thrash: Jetzt ist es jedenfalls etwas besser als vorher. In der Sache ändert das aber leider nichts. *Erstens* wird bei Maß -> mäßig kein Vokal zwischen Stamm des Nomens und Suffix gesetzt, vielmehr wird ein Vokal des Wortstamms in einen Umlaut geändert. Es ist also eine andere Fallgruppe der Derivation betroffen. *Zweitens* sehe ich immer noch keinen Grund, aus solchen Einzelbeispielen (es gibt noch dutzende andere Varianten mit anderen Suffixen und Wortstammänderungen) irgendeine Regel für die "korrekte" Suffigierung antiker Personennamen abzuleiten. Genau **das** bleibt weiterhin beliebig.

Comment: Warum sollte *Pythagor* der Stamm sein und nicht *Pythagora* oder *Pythagoras*? Kannst du Griechisch? Was heißt denn *Pythagor*? (Siehe auch unten die Antwort von Björn Friedrich.)

Comment: @Thrash: Hast Du Dir die von guidot verlinkte Wiki-Seite angesehen? Ja, ich habe das Graecum, aber Google (oder eine vernünftige Stadtbibliothek) tut es hier auch. Griechische Eigennamen werden ebenso wie lateinische (und teilweise auch deutsche - "Merkels Fraktion...") dekliniert, indem die Kasusendung entsprechend angepasst wird. In alten deutsprachigen Texten findet man sogar noch die Deklination nach lateinischen Regeln ("Aber die in Christum glauben hier..."). Aber darauf kommt es gar nicht zentral an - sondern weiterhin auf die Beliebigkeit des Arguments...

Comment: Pythagorassig wäre auch nach meinem Geschmack. ;)

Answer (score 2):

User34107 vertritt in [seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46571/1487) die durchaus plausibel klingende These, *»pythagoreisch«* wäre ein Anglizismus, und *»pythagoräisch«* wäre in Wahrheit die ursprüngliche und häufigere Form. Das dachte ich zuerst auch, aber meine Recherchen haben ergeben, dass das wohl eher nicht der Fall ist (siehe weiter unten).

Er hat aber ein Wortpaar gefunden, dessen Ableitung nach demselben Schema verläuft:

- Pythagoras → pythagoräisch
- Europa → europäisch

Ich habe nach weiteren solchen Beispielen gesucht. In meiner persönlichen Wörter-Datenbank finde ich neben vielen Zusammensetzungen (osteuropäisch, neuhebräisch) aber sonst nur diese Adjektive, die auf *»-äisch«* enden (häufige zuerst, seltene am Ende der Liste):

> hebräisch, aramäisch, chaldäisch, ptolemäisch, pharisäisch, kanaanäisch, trochäisch, archäisch, alkäisch, pygmäisch

Das sind die Begriffe, von denen sich diese Adjektive ableiten (in derselben Reihenfolge):

> Die Hebräer, die Aramäer, die Chaldäer, Ptolemäus bzw. die Ptolemäer, die Pharisäer, die Kanaanäer, ein Trochäus, das Archäikum, Alkaios, die Pygmäen

In dieser Liste gibt es nur einen Eigennamen, bei dem aus einem *a* ein *ä* wird (in allen anderen Fällen bleibt ein bereits vorhandenes *ä* erhalten):

- **Alkaios** (ein Dichter des antiken Griechenland) → **alkäisch** (Bezeichnung einer antiken Strophenform)

Hier ist das *a* aber nicht mehr in der Endsilbe. Beim Bilden des Adjektivs bleibt einem also nichts anderes übrig, als daraus *»alkaisch«* oder *»alkäisch«*. Warum sich *»alkäisch«* gegenüber *»alkaisch«* durchgesetzt hat, weiß ich aber nicht.

Die Liste *(Pythagoras, Europa)* scheint also vollständig zu sein.

---

Ich habe auch nach Adjektiven gesucht, die auf *»-eisch«* enden, und habe außer *»pythagoreisch«* (und *»unterseeisch«*, das aber aus anderen Gründen nicht dazu passt) noch das gefunden (ebenfalls nach Häufigkeit sortiert):

> eritreisch, guineisch, augusteisch, galileisch, prometheisch, epikureisch, proteisch, mediceisch, hyperboreisch, odysseisch, priapeisch

Die dazugehörigen Grundwörter:

> Eritrea, Guinea, Augustus, Galileo, Prometheus, Epikur, Proteus, die Medici, Hyperborea (ein mythisches Land nördlich des Polarkreises), Odysseus und Priapos.

Zwei Dinge fallen auf:

1. Alle drei Grundwörter in dieser Liste, die in der Endsilbe ein *a* enthalten (Eritrea, Guinea, Hyperborea), enden auf *»-ea«*, wobei das *a* bei der Bildung des Adjektivs abfällt und nur mehr das *e* (aus dem dann aber kein *ä* mehr werden kann) im Adjektiv erhalten bleibt.
2. Alle Eigennamen, die weder ein *a* noch ein *e* oder ein *ä* in der Endsilbe enthalten, werden zu einem Adjektiv, das auf *»-**e**isch«* endet. (Augustus, Epikur, die Medici, Priapos)

Somit drängt sich der Verdacht auf, dass die Endung *»-**e**isch«* die bevorzugte Variante ist, während *»-**ä**isch«* nur genommen wird, wenn es nicht anders geht.

---

Das müsste aber bedeuten, dass (wie der Fragesteller behautet hat) die Form *»pythagor**e**isch«* tatsächlich häufiger sein müsste als *»pythagor**ä**isch«*.

Das kann ein Google Ngram gut klären:

[image: Ngram »pythagoreisch« »pythagoräisch«]
[Ngram »pythagoreisch« »pythagoräisch«](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pythagoreisch%2C%20pythagor%C3%A4isch&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpythagoreisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpythagor%C3%A4isch%3B%2Cc0)

Das ist tatsächlich der Fall, und zwar schon seit mindestens rund 180 Jahren (mit einem kurzen Ausreißer während des 2. Weltkrieges, wo es offenbar opportun war, *»pythagoräisch«* den Vorzug zugeben).

Ein ähnliches Bild ergibt sich bei häufig verwendeten Beugungen:

[image: Ngram »pythagoreische« »pythagoräische«]
[Ngram »pythagoreische« »pythagoräische«](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pythagoreische%2Cpythagor%C3%A4ische&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpythagoreische%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpythagor%C3%A4ische%3B%2Cc0)

Sowie:

[image: Ngram »pythagoreisches« »pythagoräisches«]
[Ngram »pythagoreisches« »pythagoräisches«](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pythagoreisches%2Cpythagor%C3%A4isches&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpythagoreisches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpythagor%C3%A4isches%3B%2Cc0)

Die Form mit *e* ist im Schnitt ca. 3- bis 5-mal häufiger als die Form mit *ä*, und das seit mindestens der Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts.

Die Behauptung, »pythagoräisch« wäre die häufigere Form, stimmt also nicht, und auch die Behauptung, »pythagoreisch« wäre ein Anglizismus, gerät damit gehörig ins Wanken, denn die meisten Anglizismen traten erst nach 1945 in den deutschen Sprachraum ein.

---

Ich glaube daher folgendes:

> Wenn aus einem Eigennamen ein Adjektiv abgeleitet wird, das auf *»-eisch«* oder *»-äisch«* enden soll, dann ist *»-**e**isch«* immer die erste Wahl. Die Variante *»-**ä**isch«* wird nur verwendet, wenn bereits der Eigenname ein *ä* enthält. 
>   Daher muss aus *»Pythagoras«* das Adjektiv »pythagor**e**isch« werden.
>   (Auch die »[Pythagor**e**er](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoreer)« entstehen nach demselben Mechanismus.)

Warum es neben »pythagor**e**isch« und »Pythagor**e**er« auch noch die Nebenformen »pythagor**ä**isch« und »Pythagor**ä**er« gibt, ist nicht ganz klar. Vermutlich liegt das daran, dass diese genannten Ableitungen viel seltener Vorkommen als die von Fragesteller genannten Umlautungen (*Apfel → Äpfel*), und dass hier dieser Umlautungsmechanismus angewendet wurde, obwohl er hier eigentlich fehl am Platz ist.

Offenbar gab es in den letzten rund 200 Jahren aber immer genügend Menschen, die »pythagor**ä**isch« und »Pythagor**ä**er« für richtig hielten, so dass sich diese Schreibweisen als Nebenformen etablieren konnten.

Comment: Ich denke eher, dass das "ä" aus einer missverstandenen verballhornten lateinischen Deklination kommt.

Answer (score 1):

Die Schreibung im Deutschen folgt hier in beiden Schreibweisen der altgriechischen Schreibung, das eine Mal vom Nominativ, das andere Mal vom Genetiv abgeleitet. Nominativ: Πυθαγόρας (Betonung übrigens auf der vorletzten Silbe), davon abgeleitet:im Dtsch. a vor i umgelautet, im Griech. ionische Nominativendung des Namens: -ρης > Πυθαγόρειος (Adjektiv) Vokalverkürzung von η vor ιο zu ε im adjektivischen Suffix -ιος. Beide Versionen können also als richtig gelten.
”Hebräer“ folgt auch der griechischen Schreibung, nicht der hebräischen. ’Εβραίος, Gen. Εβραίου > ’Εβραίκος (adj.), αι umgefärbt zu Umlaut, kein e, daher nur analog zur obigen Nominativableitung.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt bei der Adjektivierung eines Substantivs keine Verpflichtung, das Substantiv komplett zu übernehmen, sondern eher die Tendenz, sich auf den Stamm zu konzentrieren und Endungen abzutrennen, vergleiche z. B. Hymnus -> hymnisch.

Im Griechischen würde ich -os, -as und -is zu den Endungen rechnen, damit gehört das "a" nicht mehr zum Stamm.

Vergleiche auch *Epikuros* -> *epikureisch*, wo ein Unterschied ist, dass sich die Endung *-os* in der Eindeutschung des Namens schon früher verloren hat. (Das entsprechende *epikuröisch* habe ich tatsächlich nie gelesen.)

Comment: Ich kann zwar kein griechisch, bin mir aber ziemlich sicher, dass das _-as_ bei _Pythagoras_ keine Endung ist, die an einen vermeintlichen Stamm, _Pythagor_, angehängt wurde.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altgriechische_Flexion), erste Deklination, erste Spalte?